# Is "Track Changes" a document or a user property?

Tags: ms-word

Basically, I want to know, when I select to track changes in a document, whether this selection will still be on when I send this document to someone, or if I have to remind my correspondent to not forget to select this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most definetely a document property.

However, if the other user is not using Microsoft Word, it might be ignored.